# Javascript onclick confirm window.location.href not working in Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

The following apparently simple JavaScript works fine in IE, but fails in Chrome and Safari — it doesn't fire the confirm box.

```
onclick="if(confirm('DELETE - Are you sure??')) 
window.location.href='myDeleteUrlHere';
return false;"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: [Works fine on Chrome.](https://jsfiddle.net/j8zkphz5/)

Comment: Seems to work fine in those browsers too. Are you sure javascript is enabled in the browers?

Comment: Javascript is enabled within Chrome, but still doesn't seem to work. <button type="button" onclick="if (confirm('DELETE - Are you sure??')) window.location.href='myUrl'; return false;">Delete</button>

Comment: Problem seems to be related to a line within the web.config file, when removed the same command works fine, unsure as to why this would fail though?   <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self';" />

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to return `false`. The following works fine.

```
if(confirm('Are You Sure?')) window.location.href="https://www.google.com";
```